# Excel: How do get answer with 3 conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having a little problem with this formula.

I want any empty dates to say "Missing", but under these conditions:

```
Here are my columns:
A - Sent? (Yes/No)
B - Signed? (Yes/No)
C - Date Signed
```

I want the formula to say: `If A = Yes and B= Yes and C= (Empty)` give me "Missing", if `C` has a date, give me the date.

And if A/B are empty or has any other combination that isn't 'Yes" & 'Yes', it should return as an empty cell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what if A or B is `No` or Empty?

Comment: If A or B is empty or No, then C should be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(A1="Yes",B1="Yes"),IF(C1="","Missing",C1),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
=IF(AND(A2="Yes",B2="Yes",C2<>""),C2,"MISSING")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C1)),IF(AND(IF(A1="Yes",1,0),IF(B1="Yes",1,0)),C1,"Missing"),"Missing")
```

Here is the output.
[image: Output all combinations]